# Use Java class file in IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation

Is it possible to use a class from a `.class` file in IDEA? For example, if I have a directory with two files `Ball.java` and `DemoBall.class`, how would I use `DemoBall` in `Ball`? It says it `cannot find symbol` when compiling. I just want to tell IDEA that there is a compiled Java class in the directory and to recognize that, I don't want to decompile it.

Comment: Simply create a class, containing main method, in `src` folder in __IntelliJIDEA`. Now `Run` this class, so that `out` folder gets created. Now through `Windows Explorer/File System` just go to `out` folder and paste `DemoBall.class` inside `production\ProjectName` folder. Now simply write the code that uses this `DemoBall` inside the class having the `main` method. It works fine, on my side.

Comment: @nIcEcOw Could you add this as an answer, so I can accept it? It worked great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

1. Open **IntelliJIDEA**. Now Press <kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. This will open **Project Structure**.
2. Now Select **Module** from ***Project Settings*** (left hand side). And **Dependencies** tab from the right hand side.
3. Now Click on the **+** on the extreme right hand side toolbar. Select **Jars or Directories**. A new Window, **Attack File or Directories** will pop up.
4. Now browse to the location, where `DemoBall.class` is located. Click OK.
5. Select the **CheckBox** under **Export** against the location just selected. Click OK on the main **Project Structure** window. You are done.

**Original(This one it seems is not the right way):**

1. Open **IntelliJDEA**. Create a `Project`, with simple `Java Class` named `Ball.java`
   inside it, having one `main` method(empty body).
2. Run this class, so as to create one `out` folder.
3. Copy `DemoBall.class`. Now through `Windows Explorer/File System`, go to `out` folder and paste `DemoBall.class` inside `out\production\ProjectName` folder.
4. Now simply write the code that uses this `DemoBall` class, inside the `main` method of `Ball.java` class.

Previously, I was wondering, as to why the red lines are coming still, even though, the program is running fine. But once, I restart, **IntelliJIDEA**, everythingy works fine, without showing any errors.

Comment: @saulshanabrook: If you knew how to refresh the project, then please do provide those steps too. Glad the answer did helped in some way :-)

Comment: Thanks for the point about the red lines, I was encountering that as well.